# How to Auto-start an Android Application?

Tags: android

I'm not sure how to autostart an android application after the android emulator completes its booting. Does anyone have any code snippets that will help me?

Comment: @AdamC You are wrong - see Prashast's answer.

Comment: @Rajapandian  Owner should accept an answer if it is a working solution, or mention your expectations in the comments. It would be helpful for others.

Comment: http://karanbalkar.com/2014/01/autostart-application-at-bootup-in-android/

Answer (score 53):

You have to add a manifest permission entry:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

(of course you should list all other permissions that your app uses).

Then, implement BroadcastReceiver class, it should be simple and fast executable. The best approach is to set an alarm in this receiver to wake up your service (if it's not necessary to keep it running ale the time as Prahast wrote).

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pi);
    }
}
```

Then, add a Receiver class to your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".receivers.BootUpReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: What is the interval?

Comment: the ".receivers" in this line      <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".receivers.BootUpReceiver"
gives error "Unresolvable package receivers"

Comment: @asmgx - if you created class "BootUpReceiver" in your app's src root folder, then change that to `... android:name="BootUpReceiver"`. Or maybe need "." before the class name.  I think Krzysztof has his in a subfolder named "receivers".

Answer (score 30):

Edit your  `AndroidManifest.xml` to add `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Edit your  `AndroidManifest.xml` application-part for below Permission

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now write below in Activity.

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Work without `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` line only!!!

Answer (score 13):

If by autostart you mean auto start on phone bootup then you should register a BroadcastReceiver for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` Intent. Android systems broadcasts that intent once boot is completed.

Once you receive that intent you can launch a Service that can do whatever you want to do.

Keep note though that having a Service running all the time on the phone is generally a bad idea as it eats up system resources even when it is idle. You should launch your Service / application only when needed and then stop it when not required.

Answer (score 2):

I always get in here, for this topic. I'll put my code in here so i (or other) can use it next time. (Phew hate to search into my repository code).

Add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Add receiver and service:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="Launcher" />
```

Create class Launcher:

```
public class Launcher extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        new AsyncTask<Service, Void, Service>() {

            @Override
            protected Service doInBackground(Service... params) {
                Service service = params[0];
                PackageManager pm = service.getPackageManager();
                try {
                    Intent target = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("your.package.id");
                    if (target != null) {
                        service.startActivity(target);
                        synchronized (this) {
                            wait(3000);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
                    }
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException | InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
                return service;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Service service) {
                service.stopSelf();
            }

        }.execute(this);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Create class `BootUpReceiver` to do action after android reboot.

For example launch MainActivity:

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent target = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
        target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(target);  
    }
}
```

Comment: error on         <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
Unresolvable class BootUpReceiver

Comment: @asmgx: I've update the answer. Forgot to put it in there.

Comment: class Launcher are not used

Comment: @letroll sorry for long respond. I am inactive for longtime. I believe Launcher class being used in the manifest as a service. CMIIW. I have not tried this anymore, i use flutter now.