# Run my application in background when i start device power on in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to create startup application in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912209/how-to-create-startup-application-in-android)
>   [How to Autostart an Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056570/how-to-autostart-an-android-application)

Hi,

I am trying in one of my application when i am going to start i mean power on my google android g1 my application automatically will start but i am unable to understand how can 
i do that please help......

Comment: IIRC, android apps are either 'screen' or 'service'.  What you want to do is install a service on your phone.  Search down that path.

Comment: It is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056570/how-to-autostart-an-android-application

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a basic example of what I think you're trying to do.  You'll need to do a few things.  First, grant your application permission to listen for a "Boot completed" signal.  In your AndroidManifest.xml, add this line in the manifest section:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Under your application section, add and specify a broadcast receiver for this intent:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You also need a broadcast receiver which will respond to this intent and start your service at boot.  Create MyBroadcastReceiver.java in your project:

```
package com.mypackage.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent aIntent) {

        // This is where you start your service
        aContext.startService(new Intent(aContext, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: : The method startService(Intent) is undefined for the type MyBroadcastReceiver , it also underlines MyService.