# Starting android activity on boot in Background

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to start the app after boot completing in Background.
I don't want to show the UI.

This is my code, it starts the app as if I clicked its icon, but I need to hide it!

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted },
    Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault }
)]
public class ReceiveBoot: BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        if ((intent.Action != null) &&
            (intent.Action ==
                Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted))
        { 

            Android.Content.Intent start = new Android.Content.Intent(context, typeof(Main_Activity));
            start.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            start.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.FromBackground);
            context.ApplicationContext.StartActivity(start);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I don't want to show the UI*. Then you don't need a Activity. Probably a service.

Comment: in short not possible, if you have has atleast 1 activity, starting it after reboot will show UI. If it does not contain and UI then it can be started as a service. For [How to start app after reboot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2974763/1061944)

Answer (score 3):

If you need an `Activity` with no UI, you probably want a service.

Move the logic you need to execute at boot from your `Activity` to a `Service`  (more info on it [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/)).

Then, in order to start it, just change your intent a to use `typeof(MyServiceClass)`, set whichever flag you may need and call [`StartService`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.StartService(Android.Content.Intent)/) instead of `StartActivity`