# Android autostart functionality

Tags: android

I am working on one application which basically is an auto-start application and runs in background.

The problem is I need to access shared preference before auto start. But if device is not properly booted up how can I access the shared preference?

I want that either if device is completely booted then start my service or I can set any wait to my service to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912209/how-to-create-startup-application-in-android).

You should use the permission `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` and register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`