# Autostart application while phone boots up

Tags: android, autostart

How can I make my application to get started while my phone boots up itself.

Comment: Did you even try Google? http://www.androidsoftwaredeveloper.com/2009/03/20/how-to-start-on-boot/

Comment: Duplicate of (amongst others): [How to Autostart an Android Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056570/how-to-autostart-an-android-application)

Answer (score 11):

You need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` with `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent.

Add following to your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="MyApp_Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyApp_Receiver class implementing [BoradcastReciever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Implement the onReceive() method and start your favorite activity from your app.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // make sure you receive "BOOT_COMPLETED"
    if ((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")))
    {
        // Start the service or activity 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Guys, your input will surely find me the solution that i am trying for...Thanks a lot...