# Automatically forward port on start?

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I need to forward a port on an android emulator, right now I had to type the command every time:

`adb forward tcp:23946 tcp:23946`

Is there any way to make this automatic? I tried to replace adb with a script but that command won't work until the device is up and running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634041/detect-when-android-emulator-is-fully-booted) (which I've tested and works, though it wasn't for a scenario like this one), you could simply write a script that waits until the emulator is booted.

Something like (pseudocode, don't know which platform you're on) :)

```
emulator @emulator-name
while ('adb shell getprop init.svc.bootanim' == "running") sleep(10s)
adb forward tcp:23946 tcp:23946
```