# Booting with Android App

Tags: android, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Autostart application while phone boots up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618114/autostart-application-while-phone-boots-up)

This seems like a fairly simple question but I have not been able to find an answer.

I've been looking at getting tablets for my business, however, I want them to boot straight to an App.

If I'm not saying that right, I mean, every time I turn on the device, I want it to load straight to 'Angry Birds' (or my developed app). Is this possible, and if so, is it widely known how?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 Whether this is a duplicate or not, it helped me!

Comment: Even though this is marked as a Duplicate, this one has the best answer as HOME, while all the rest have BOOT_COMPLETED.

Answer (score 5):

Make your app be the home screen, by adding the `HOME` category to your activity's `<intent-filter>`:

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BOOT_COMPLETED Reciever and start your Activity inside

Edit: Use code like below

```
public class MyBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(startIntent);
    }
}
```

And in your Mandifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Comment: This will be unreliable, as you might launch your activity before the home screen activity comes to the foreground.