# how to start android phone with custom launcher

Tags: android, android-theme, android-launcher

I want to create theme, for that i created one launcher app. So when i press "home" button it shows me to select which launcher to be launch.

But I don't want that selection UI, When my app is installed it should launch automatically and sets it as default launcher.

can it be possible?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not, and for good reason. Users want control, and automatically changing their launcher will just anger people.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but Is there any way so that when i start the phone my app launches automatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6391902/291827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  No system service can be overridden by default without the user getting to choose.  This is for security-  otherwise any app could fool people into downloading them, take over for that service (in this case the launcher), and prevent the user from being able to use his phone.  The launcher would be particularly bad-  it could prevent you from opening settings or launching other apps at all.  Huge malware risk.  That's why the user has to choose for services like the launcher, keyboard, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your question is NO. You can just autostart you app on device reboot. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097304/1616443)