# How to enable auto start automatically just after installing app from play store

Tags: android, bootcompleted

As we know when we are installing app like **WhatsApp** , **Facebook** etc. from play store then it automatically listed in a list of autostart application on boot.

**As shown in below screenshot** we can see how these application are listed in autostart application which automatically turned on after installing.

[image]

So my question is how can I list my app in the auto-launch apps list. After installing my app, its showing in list but its not enabled. But I want that after installing it should automatically enable.

I know there is a way to achieve this. Please help I didn't found any articles about this.

Comment: you need to ask user to enable auto start app permission once app started.

Comment: But why other apps dont ask how they are achieving this , @Shailesh

Comment: These apps are already white-listed by manufacturers while Android OS is loaded on device, but we need to do manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, this can't be achieved by every app. The apps you see, which are automatically auto-launching after installation are white-listed by manufacturers or Google themselves. All you can do is send the user to the specific settings to enable the auto-launch after installing the app. This is also described here:

[Add my app to AutoStart apps list in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791150/add-my-app-to-autostart-apps-list-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: But we can make whitelisted app . What if we are making any commercial in a company..

Comment: Many other apps having features of auto launching telegram itself having this  feature. I think there is a way but many of us dont know @Noltibus

Comment: This white-listing needs to be done by the phone manufacturer, there is no way of auto launching an app without any user interaction first if you are not specifically white-listed by the manufacturer of every phone there is (afaik)

Comment: You mean if we want to auto launch our app then we have to do tell the manufacturer for enabling whitelisting of this app? @Noltibus

Comment: Yes, but a way better way would be to just depend on the user to open the app once after installing and then tell the user to go to the settings of his phone to enable auto-launching your app. You can even send the user to the correct place in his settings, which is shown in the SO link I posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Noltibus I understood .