# how to enable "auto-start" by default in Android Application

Tags: android, kotlin, autostart, bootcompleted

I've encountered an issue with my BroadcastReceiver for the *BOOT_COMPLETED* action. Despite declaring the necessary permissions and configuring the BroadcastReceiver (AlarmBroadcastReceiver) in the AndroidManifest.xml, it only seems to work when I manually start the app at least once after a reboot.

Here's a snippet from my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk />

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


    <application
        android:name=".HealthCareApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:targetApi="n">

        <receiver
            android:name=".feature.scheduler.services.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AlarmBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var stateManager: StateManager
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when (intent?.action) {
            ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED -> {
                startRescheduleAlarmsService(context!!)
            }

            ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED -> {
                startRescheduleAlarmsService(context!!)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startRescheduleAlarmsService(context: Context) {
        Log.d("TAG", "startRescheduleAlarmsService: ")
        val toastText = String.format("Alarm Reboot")
        Toast.makeText(context, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        stateManager.rescheduleAlarm(context)
    }
}
```

I've also been trying to figure out how to enable auto-start permissions by default for my app, so the BroadcastReceiver works without manual user interaction.

I'd appreciate any guidance on resolving the issue with the BroadcastReceiver not functioning automatically on boot and any suggestions on ensuring auto-start permissions by default. Thank you for your assistance!

Permission ScreenShot:
[Flipkart auto-launch is enable by default in Realme(Android13)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReUO9.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to do on boot? Start an Activity which is visible to the user? Or maybe connect to a server?

Comment: I have to reschedule alarms

Answer (score 0):

I found your answer in another thread. here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097304/13295974) to it.

But if you want it in Kotlin just use Android studio code convertor Java to Kotlin.

Have a nice day.

Comment: But he already did everything what is explained in the link.

Comment: I remember that some receiver actions don't work together, maybe that's the point. @zomega

Comment: I try with single action but result is same
` <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Comment: I believe there is a permission for that which you can disable or enable in phone settings (background autostart in my phone), maybe that's the problem.